# Allocating large memory in C (Project Euler Prob)

Tags: c, arrays, math, memory-management

I was trying to solve a problem using C on project euler [click here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=16)
Here is the code. It works fine for 10 values but for 1000 values it gives a wrong output. I noticed that it gives a right output till 32. I think I'm exceeding the memory or something. How do I allocate memory for such a large array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    int a[10], i, sum=1, b=0;

    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 
        a[0] = 1;
        a[i] = sum + a[i-1];
        sum = sum + a[i-1];
    }

    for(int j = 1;j > 0; j++) {
        b = b + sum%10;

        if(sum<10)
            break;

        sum = sum/10;
     }

     printf("%d\n",b);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The type `int` is not capable of holding valus as large as required. You need to solve the problem with a different approach (hint: use arrays of `char` to represent the numbers as strings).

Comment: If my copy/paste abilities are sharp, 2 to the power 1000 is `10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069###` (last 3 digits censored)

Comment: Just use Wolfram Alpha, lol.

Comment: That won't even fit into a uint64_t, sadly. There two ways now, either use GMP, or a slightly controversial "use Python", since large numbers come in its standard library by default. Or of course, roll your own :P

Comment: Examine the powers of 2 that you can print out. Look at each digit position, see if you can deduce a pattern. Look the sum of the digits. Is there a pattern there? Look at what happens are you go from 2**i to 2**(i+1). Are there any patterns there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try computing 2<sup>1000</sup> as an 80-bit `long double`, then using `sprintf` to convert it to a string, then summing the digits of that string.

Why this works:

Floating-point types store numbers as a mantissa times an exponent.  The exponent is always a power of two, and the mantissa can be 1.  For a `long double`, the exponent can be up to 2<sup>16383</sup>.  `printf` and friends, on modern implementations, will correctly print out the digits of a floating-point number.

Code:

```
int main() {
  char buf[1024]; int ans = 0;
  sprintf(buf, "%.0f", 0x1.0p1000);
  for (int i = 0; buf[i]; i++) ans += buf[i] - '0';
  printf("%i\n", ans);
}
```

Comment: Don't represent with an integral type.  (I never said you should.)  Represent it as a `long double` like I said.  Then you can compute it exactly to a string using `sprintf`, like I said.  It's trivial to compute 2<sup>1000</sup> exactly as a `long double`.

Comment: But that is jut binary representation. it sais 2^1000, but not what decimal digits are.

Comment: Yes i do. Have you tried coding on what are you talking about? Can you get more than 20 digits output? Please post code.

Comment: Yes.  And it works.  How do you think I solved this problem?  Have you tried?

Comment: +1 Simply brilliant. You could post the code for the skeptics, though.

Comment: I'm halfway of a mind not to ruin the problem by doing that.  But...OK.

Comment: @tmyklebu: But what do you do, if there's no printf? Or if the challenge forbids using it, or floating point numbers? Maybe I should add code to my answer as well…

Comment: @datenwolf: Then you can't outsource solving this problem to the C library.  You can do repeated integer addition (the way we all learned in grade one) in base ten 999 times, handling carries and all that fun stuff yourself.  (As you mentioned, though, learning your tools is half the point of the early Project Euler problems, so I have to wonder why we're dealing with this hypothetical situation.)

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that it gives a right output till 32

That is, because the integer type you're using has 32 bits. It simply can't hold larger numbers. You can't solve it the conventional way.

Here's what I'd suggest: First let's estimate how many digits that number will have. Every time a number gets 10-fold in decimal writing a new digit is required. So the number of digits for a number in decimal is given by ceil(log10(n)). So for 2^1000 you need ceil(log10(2^1000)) digits, but that is just ceil(1000*log10(2)) = 302, so you'll need 302 decimal digits to write it down.

This gives the next idea: Write down the number 1 in 302 digits, i.e. 301 times '0' and one '1' in a string. Then double the string 1000 times, by adding it to itself just like in elementary school, carrying the overflowing digits.

---

*EDIT* I think I should point out, that the problem encountered is the whole point of this Project Euler problem. Project Euler problems all have in common, that you can not solve them by using naive programming methods. You must get creative to solve them!